# how to convert mib to mb i want to test ram

Tags: c++, c, testing, memory-management

I am trying to test how much RAM a 32 bit OS supports.

**Hi i am converting app from 32 bit os to 64 bit os Just checking looking will 4gb ram is sufficient this is what i want to check**

what all occupies more memory i know pointers will double please help me below program **such that program works for MB not MIB**

I tried this program but I am missing some method for the conversion of MiB to MB.

How can I get below program to work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        size_t oneHundredMiB=100*1048576;
        size_t maxMemMiB=0;
        void *memPointer = NULL;
        while((memPointer = malloc(maxMemMiB += oneHundredMiB)) != NULL) {
                printf("Max Tested Memory = %zi\n",maxMemMiB);
                memset(memPointer,0,maxMemMiB);
                free(memPointer);
        }
        printf("Max Usable Memory aprox = %zi\n",maxMemMiB-oneHundredMiB);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. To convert to MB, value is `(MiB * 1000/1024)` I think

Comment: You should use, perhaps by writing and reading some random elements, the `memPointer`. Otherwise, a clever optimizing compiler might remove it. And some operating systems (e.g. some, but not all, Linux distributions) have overcommitment in their `malloc` memory allocation....

Comment: thanks for quick reply will the state ment look like this in program oneHundredMiB=100*1048576/1000

Comment: to calculate in gb how my program should be converted or mb is also fine

Comment: Note that the OS might prevent a process from allocating the entire physically available RAM.

Comment: Hi mooooeeep how to check how much dynamic memory on RAM

Comment: Hi i am converting app from 32 bit os to 64 bit os Just checking looking will 4gb ram is sufficient this is what i want to check

Comment: On what operating system, and with what compiler, are you porting your app from 32 bits to 64 bits? Why do you care about RAM??? some weird users might run your app, swapping the virtual memory to some fast disk, with a bit less RAM than the virtual memory used.

Comment: Most 32 bits Linux systems support at most 3Gbytes of application usable virtual space, even on machines with 4Gbytes or more. On Linux you could use `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/meminfo` to get precise informations. And users may limit your process using `setrlimit` syscall.